# Azure mac hosted Agent : installing gem install , downloading old version gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-devops, rubygems, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, azure-devops-pipelines

im running Hosted mac agent and i noticed that when i run this command in the pipeline :

```
- job: mac_agent
  dependsOn: self_hosted_connect
  timeoutInMinutes: 30
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    workspace:
      clean: all
      
  steps:
  - task: UseRubyVersion@0
    inputs:
     versionSpec: '>= 2.4'
     addToPath: true
       
 
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    inputs:
      buildType: 'current'
      downloadType: 'single'
      artifactName: 'ios_artifacts'
      downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

  - script:  |
     gem cleanup
     gem install --no-document bundler
     bundle update --bundler
     bundle install --retry=3 --jobs=4
     gem install fastlane
     
    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts'
    displayName: 'installing gems And Fastlane'
 
  - script:  |
     pod deintegrate
     gem install cocoapods
     pod install
     pod --version
    workingDirectory: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/ios_artifacts'
    displayName: 'pod and cocoapods install '
```

The gems versions it downloading are old although I'm not specifying any version and assuming it will download the latest. which it did until a week ago!
this is the none working version :

```
2021-01-28T10:10:02.9192650Z Cleaning up installed gems...
2021-01-28T10:10:02.9194120Z Clean up complete
2021-01-28T10:10:05.2468070Z Successfully installed bundler-2.2.7
2021-01-28T10:10:05.2468470Z 1 gem installed
2021-01-28T10:10:05.6174390Z Could not locate Gemfile
2021-01-28T10:10:06.2657430Z Could not locate Gemfile
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4111070Z Successfully installed rouge-2.0.7
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4111990Z Successfully installed xcpretty-0.3.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4112630Z Successfully installed xcpretty-travis-formatter-1.0.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4113320Z Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4113890Z Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4114500Z Successfully installed claide-1.0.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4115180Z Successfully installed CFPropertyList-2.3.6
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4115760Z Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4116390Z Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.19.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4116970Z Successfully installed word_wrap-1.0.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4117600Z Successfully installed tty-screen-0.5.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4118230Z Successfully installed unicode-display_width-1.7.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4118880Z Successfully installed terminal-table-1.8.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4119500Z Successfully installed terminal-notifier-1.8.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4120090Z Successfully installed slack-notifier-1.5.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4120730Z Successfully installed security-0.1.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4121560Z Successfully installed rubyzip-1.3.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4122200Z Successfully installed plist-3.6.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4122770Z Successfully installed multi_xml-0.6.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4123400Z Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4124000Z Successfully installed multi_json-1.15.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4124600Z Successfully installed mini_magick-4.5.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4125240Z Successfully installed highline-1.7.10
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4125790Z Successfully installed thor-1.1.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4126410Z Successfully installed webrick-1.7.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4126970Z Successfully installed jwt-2.2.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4127590Z Successfully installed faraday-0.17.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4128190Z Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.6
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4128780Z Successfully installed addressable-2.7.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4129410Z Successfully installed signet-0.14.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4129980Z Successfully installed retriable-3.1.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4130590Z Successfully installed uber-0.1.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4131170Z Successfully installed declarative-option-0.1.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4131810Z Successfully installed declarative-0.0.20
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4132420Z Successfully installed representable-3.0.4
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4132990Z Successfully installed mini_mime-1.0.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4133660Z Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4134220Z Successfully installed os-1.1.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4134840Z Successfully installed memoist-0.16.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4135410Z Successfully installed googleauth-0.15.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4136050Z Successfully installed google-apis-core-0.2.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4137530Z Successfully installed google-apis-discovery_v1-0.1.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4138130Z Successfully installed gems-1.2.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4138760Z Successfully installed zeitwerk-2.4.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4139350Z Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.8
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4139990Z Successfully installed tzinfo-2.0.4
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4140170Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4140410Z HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4140760Z But that may break your application.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4140920Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4141210Z If you are upgrading your Rails application from an older version of Rails:
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4141710Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4142330Z Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4143080Z If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4143750Z 'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4144090Z If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4144360Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4144610Z If you are starting a NEW Rails application, you can ignore this notice.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4145460Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4145710Z For more info see:
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4145970Z https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4146200Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4147410Z Successfully installed i18n-1.8.7
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4148120Z Successfully installed activesupport-6.1.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4148800Z Successfully installed google-apis-generator-0.1.2
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4149170Z *******************************************************************************
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4149980Z The google-api-client gem is deprecated and will likely not be updated further.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4150230Z 
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4150490Z Instead, please install the gem corresponding to the specific service to use.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4151290Z For example, to use the Google Drive V3 client, install google-apis-drive_v3.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4151710Z For more information, see the FAQ in the OVERVIEW.md file or the YARD docs.
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4152150Z *******************************************************************************
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4153190Z Successfully installed google-api-client-0.53.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4154210Z Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4154820Z Successfully installed fastimage-2.2.1
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4155470Z Successfully installed faraday_middleware-0.14.0
2021-01-28T10:10:20.4155800Z Building native extensions. This could take a while...
2021-01-28T10:10:35.2497360Z invalid options: -SHN
2021-01-28T10:10:35.2497770Z (invalid options are ignored)
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6773850Z Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.7
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6775230Z Successfully installed unf-0.1.4
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6776410Z Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.20190701
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6789320Z Successfully installed http-cookie-1.0.3
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6790470Z Successfully installed faraday-cookie_jar-0.0.7
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6791910Z Successfully installed excon-0.78.1
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6794970Z Successfully installed dotenv-2.7.6
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6795810Z Successfully installed commander-fastlane-4.4.6
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6796500Z Successfully installed colored-1.2
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6797090Z Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6797690Z Successfully installed babosa-1.0.4
2021-01-28T10:16:36.6798330Z Successfully installed fastlane-2.54.1
```

and this is the working version :

```
021-01-18T15:22:52.5729450Z Successfully installed bundler-2.2.5
2021-01-18T15:22:52.5731210Z 1 gem installed
2021-01-18T15:22:53.2670020Z Could not locate Gemfile
2021-01-18T15:22:53.7987180Z Could not locate Gemfile
2021-01-18T15:23:26.8921550Z Successfully installed slack-notifier-2.3.2
2021-01-18T15:23:26.8953050Z Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
2021-01-18T15:23:26.8962540Z Successfully installed CFPropertyList-3.0.3
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9064490Z Successfully installed claide-1.0.3
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9106410Z Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9107550Z Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9108470Z Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.19.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9109430Z Successfully installed rouge-2.0.7
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9110370Z Successfully installed xcpretty-0.3.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9127830Z Successfully installed terminal-notifier-2.0.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9128880Z Successfully installed unicode-display_width-1.7.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9129940Z Successfully installed terminal-table-1.8.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9130890Z Successfully installed plist-3.6.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9132410Z Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.6
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9133340Z Successfully installed addressable-2.7.0
2021-01-18T15:23:26.9180840Z Successfully installed multipart-post-2.0.0
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8142420Z Successfully installed word_wrap-1.0.0
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8149220Z Successfully installed tty-screen-0.8.1
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8150290Z Successfully installed tty-cursor-0.7.1
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8151220Z Successfully installed tty-spinner-0.9.3
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8152040Z Successfully installed babosa-1.0.4
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8152910Z Successfully installed colored-1.2
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8154190Z Successfully installed highline-1.7.10
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8155390Z Successfully installed commander-fastlane-4.4.6
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8156280Z Successfully installed excon-0.78.1
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8157200Z Successfully installed faraday-net_http-1.0.1
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8158060Z Successfully installed ruby2_keywords-0.0.2
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8158990Z Successfully installed faraday-1.3.0
2021-01-18T15:23:27.8159320Z Building native extensions. This could take a while...
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8884610Z Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.7
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8938770Z Successfully installed unf-0.1.4
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8942020Z Successfully installed domain_name-0.5.20190701
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8945190Z Successfully installed http-cookie-1.0.3
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8946460Z Successfully installed faraday-cookie_jar-0.0.7
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8947890Z Successfully installed faraday_middleware-1.0.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8948900Z Successfully installed fastimage-2.2.1
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8978150Z Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8981380Z Successfully installed mini_magick-4.11.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8982690Z Successfully installed rubyzip-2.3.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8983930Z Successfully installed security-0.1.3
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8985290Z Successfully installed xcpretty-travis-formatter-1.0.1
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8988880Z Successfully installed dotenv-2.7.6
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8990250Z Successfully installed naturally-2.2.1
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8991500Z Successfully installed simctl-1.6.8
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8992750Z Successfully installed jwt-2.2.2
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8994170Z Successfully installed declarative-option-0.1.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.8997560Z Successfully installed declarative-0.0.20
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9000700Z Successfully installed uber-0.1.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9001920Z Successfully installed representable-3.0.4
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9003150Z Successfully installed retriable-3.1.2
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9004340Z Successfully installed mini_mime-1.0.2
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9005600Z Successfully installed multi_json-1.15.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9006920Z Successfully installed signet-0.14.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9008250Z Successfully installed memoist-0.16.2
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9009400Z Successfully installed os-1.1.1
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9010660Z Successfully installed googleauth-0.14.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9012000Z Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9016350Z Successfully installed google-api-client-0.38.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9019500Z Successfully installed google-cloud-env-1.4.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9022580Z Successfully installed google-cloud-errors-1.0.1
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9023820Z Successfully installed google-cloud-core-1.5.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9040570Z Successfully installed google-apis-core-0.2.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9046810Z Successfully installed google-apis-iamcredentials_v1-0.1.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9051060Z Successfully installed google-apis-storage_v1-0.1.0
2021-01-18T15:23:38.9054080Z Building native extensions. This could take a while...
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2078850Z Successfully installed digest-crc-0.6.3
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2079760Z Successfully installed google-cloud-storage-1.30.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2080490Z Successfully installed emoji_regex-3.2.1
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2081070Z Successfully installed jmespath-1.4.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2081750Z Successfully installed aws-partitions-1.416.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2082380Z Successfully installed aws-eventstream-1.1.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2083440Z Successfully installed aws-sigv4-1.2.2
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2084060Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-core-3.111.1
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2084650Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-kms-1.41.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2085300Z Successfully installed aws-sdk-s3-1.87.0
2021-01-18T15:24:00.2085890Z Successfully installed fastlane-2.171.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, gem will install the specific version of bundle.

You can try to install a specific bundle using the script:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.7
```